# Can't write 4 in superscript in pygame? Other numbers work

Tags: python, fonts, pygame, render, superscript

I can write superscripts in python with the following code:

```py
numbers = [f"\N{SUPERSCRIPT ONE}",f"\N{SUPERSCRIPT TWO}",f"\N{SUPERSCRIPT THREE}",f"\N{SUPERSCRIPT FOUR}"]
numbers2 = ["\u00b9","\u00b2","\u00b3","\u2074"]
print(numbers)
print(numbers2)
```

However when I try to render the superscript on a pygame surface the superscripted 4 displays as an empty square instead. The other numbers work fine. I've added a picture of what my output looks like.

```py
img = font.render(str(math.floor(random.randrange(1,11))) +random.choice(numbers2),True,(0,0,0))
screen.blit(img,imgpos)
pygame.display.flip()
```

[image: code output]

Comment: Your font cannot represent the unicode character "\u2074". You must use a different font. You will likely need to stich the text using different fonts.

Comment: Thank you! Turns out a lot of fonts don't have that unicode character. Also thanks for fixing the post.